# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rake, sequel

i am using sequel gem and postgresql database

i have a file hello.rb with code

```
require "rubygems"
require './post'
require "sequel"

# connect to an in-memory database
DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://ritesh:newpassword@localhost')


post = Post['ruby1', 'hello world1']
post[1]
```

and i created a table post and
a model with code

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://ritesh:newpassword@localhost')

class Post < Sequel::Model
set_primary_key [:category, :title]

end
```

when i run command ruby hello.rb .i am getting the following error
hello.rb:10: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

first thing i want to know for creating we should create a table with that name and then create a model??
second thing if first assumption is true then why i am getting this error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct a new object in ruby you should call new. I am not sure what is post but it seems the correct syntax should be:

```
post = Post.new('ruby1', 'hello world1')
```

Otherwise post will remain null after this line.